# Set exact version for Nuget package dependency when using IncludeReferencedProjects

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution with several projects in it. Each project has it's own nuspec file and some of the projects reference each other

When I create a new package by calling

```
nuget pack MyLibrary.csproj -IncludeReferencedProject
```

nuget is clever enough to add any referenced projects as dependencies, rather than bringing in the generated binaries, but it always sets the dependency version to

```
version="1.2.3.4"
```

which is interpreted as 1.2.3.4 or higher

I want to be able to tell nuget to set the version to

```
version="[1.2.3.4]"
```

so that dependencies are always exact

Is there any way I can do this without having to manually update and maintain the dependencies in the nuspec file for every project?

Comment: Have you had any luck finding a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the packages.config file for your project, specify the version like this:

```
<packages>
  <package id="example.dll" version="1.3" targetFramework="net451" allowedVersions="[1.3]" />
</packages>
```

Comment: This provides functionality during Package-Install, Package-Update, etc.. but doesn't seem to affect "nuget pack" at all.

Comment: @MarkMelville what version of nuget did you test with? I just retested with latest version of nuget and this does affect the pack command.

Comment: How do you do this when there is no packages.config?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to write a tool that opens the generated package, changes the dependency restraints, and the saves the package. Note that you shouldn't set upper bound unless you have a really good reason to do so. See http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-2-core-algorithm.html

Comment: I was trying to find a way to do it with a nuget command, ie. without having to write an extra tool/script. I'm also not trying to set an upper bound, i'm trying to set an exact version

Answer (score 0):

Use -Properties as described here https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/336207 or just **$version$** if you use -Version to specify the package version and it is the same as the dependency version.